# Dynamic image loading to svg

Tags: javascript, svg

Situation: have an image in `svg`:

```
<filter id="svg-filter-blur">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10,10" />
</filter>

<image id='view-photo-svg' x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" 
filter="url(#svg-filter-blur)"/>
```

Tried to make this way:

```
var photo = new Image();
    photo.src = 'photos/h5.jpg';

    photo.addEventListener('load', function(){
        render();
    });
```

and in `render()`:

```
var photoDOM = document.getElementById('view-photo-svg');
    photoDOM.setAttribute('src', "url('" + photo.src + "')");
```

or

```
    photoDOM.setAttribute('xlink:href', photo.src);
```

**Doesn't work.**
Any suggestions?

Perfect scenario:

- have an access to image parameters/events(such as `onload`)
- can apply filters/clipping to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes in a non-null namespace must be set via [setAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) so you need this...

```
photoDOM.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', photo.src);
```

Comment: They were clearly in the null namespace then. Almost everything is. The distinguishing feature is the presence of a colon (:)